# Set environment variable for another user (Standalone Trac problem)

Tags: environment-variables, sudo

I'd like to run `tracd` ([Trac](http://trac.xp-dev.com/Teon/wiki/TracStandalone) in standalone mode) with custom template for multiple repository list:

```
$ tracd -p 8080 -e /my/projects/path
```

For custom template, I need an environment variable ([as said here](http://trac.xp-dev.com/Teon/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#ProjectList)):

```
$ export TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE=/path/to/template
```

My problem is, that I need to run `tracd` as another user. Now I have:

```
$ sudo -u devel tracd -d -p 8080 -e /my/projects/path
```

Running like `devel` there's no environment variable and it displays the project list on default template. I tried the obvious:

```
$ sudo -u devel export TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE=/path/to/template
sudo: export: command not found
```

**Is my approach to this completely wrong, or I can solve this with setting another user's environment variable?**

Comment: There's another obvious one: `$ sudo -u devel bash` and then `export`, which solves my problem, but I'd like to hear your opinion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can run arbitrary commands as the `devel` user, a common idiom is

```
sudo -u devel env TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE=/path/to/template tracd -d -p 8080 -e /my/projects/path
```

If you have root permissions, you can tell `sudo` to retain the environment variable with the `env_keep` directive, e.g.

```
Defaults>devel: env_keep=TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE
```